# ggplot - stacked bar-plot: Show mean of bars on top of each stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

This is a screenshot of part of my stacked bar-plot. I would like to have the mean values of each of the bars on top of each of the stacked bars

[image]

I have tried to include another df with my means through geom_text in the code.
However, since the dfs differ in size it did not work I think. I also tried to directly include the mean through calculating it with the geom_text function. What are your suggestions?

```
ggplot(Df_class, aes(x = series, y = Class, group = Month, color = Month + label = Class)) + geom_col(position = "stack",show.legend = T) + 
labs(x = "BG ID", y = "Class Total",title ="Class Total") + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = rel(0.45))) + 
  geom_text(aes(Df_class_mean$Mean_Class, size = 3, nudge_y = 0, vjust = 0.45))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: structure(list(Number = c(4, 8, 7, 6, 3, 5), series = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A02_1y", "A02_2y", "A03_1", 
"A03_2x", "A05_1x", "A05_2y", "A06_1", "A06_2", "A07_1", "A07_2z", 
"B02_1z", "B02_2z", "B03_1z", "B03_2y", "B04_1", "B04_2", "B05_1z", 
"B05_2", "B06_1z", "B06_2", "B07_1z", "B07_2z", "C02_1z", "C02_2z", 
"C03_1", "C03_2z", "C04_1", "C04_2", "C05_1", "C05_2", "C06_1", 
"C06_2", "C07_1x", "C07_2y", "D02_1", "D02_2", "D03_1", "D03_2x", 
"D06_1", "D06_2z", "Month"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")